# How to add onchange/onclick event in jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add on click event listener with each check box. 
please help.[demo](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)

Comment: Its there in the same page `http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#callbacks`

Answer (score 1):

Well everything is well documented in this page http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#callbacks

```
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect({
        click: function(event, ui){
            //your stuff here
        }
    });
});
```